# Double-click on Motorla Xoom seems to reset viewport width

Tags: android, mobile

I'm working on a fairly simple mobile site. When I inherited the codebase, it did not have a viewport `meta` tag in it, and the client complained that on the Mototola Xoom the content only took up 3/4 of the screen width. The problem was that the viewport with was less than the actual screen width; adding the following meta tag solved the problem:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

No everything is working fine, until double-clicking the screen, in which case the original behavior comes back. Pinch-zooming works fine, this is specifically a double-click issue. Can anyone provide any guidance on how to avoid this issue? I already know I can simply set `user-scalable=no`, but the client wants to have zoom work, preferably for both pinching and double-clicking.

Thank you